# Mockito MockedStatic when() "Cannot resolve method"

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I am trying to use Mockito MockedStatic to mock a static method.

I am using mockito-core and mockito-inline version 3.6.0 with Spring Boot and maven.

I can't manage to make the mock work, I have a "Cannot resolve method post" on the `Unirest::post` that you can see in the code below:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    try (MockedStatic<Unirest> mock = Mockito.mockStatic(Unirest.class)) {
        mock.when(Unirest::post).thenReturn(new HttpRequestWithBody(HttpMethod.POST, "url"));
    }
}
```

The Unirest class comes from the [unirest-java](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/blob/main/unirest/src/main/java/kong/unirest/Unirest.java) package.

Did someone encounter this issue already and have a solution?

Comment: can you please add your `Unirest` class to your question

Comment: @rieckpil I added the link to the question: https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/blob/main/unirest/src/main/java/kong/unirest/Unirest.java

Comment: can you also please add the full stack trace of your failing test case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `Unirest.post(String url)` takes an argument and hence you can't refer to it using `Unirest::post`.

You can use the following:

```
@Test
void testRequest() {
  try (MockedStatic<Unirest> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Unirest.class)) {
    mockedStatic.when(() -> Unirest.post(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(...);
    someService.doRequest();
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that you have to mock now the whole `Unirest` usage and every method call on it as the mock returns `null` by default.

If you want to test your HTTP clients take a look at [WireMock](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-integration-tests-with-wiremock-and-junit-5/) or the [MockWebServer](https://rieckpil.de/test-spring-webclient-with-mockwebserver-from-okhttp/) from OkHttp. This way you test your clients with real HTTP communication and can test also corner cases like slow responses or 5xx HTTP codes.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Though, as you proposed, I used MockServer instead to assert the request generated